# Selberg sieve for counting monic irreducible $P \in \mathbb{F}_q[t]$ such that $P + K$ is also irreducible

Tags: nt.number-theory, sieve-theory, function-fields

In a 1983 paper by William Webb (link below), the author gives a version of the Selberg sieve for function fields and uses it to prove that for a fixed $K \in \mathbb{F}_q[t]$, the number $\mathcal{N}(n,K)$ of monic irreducible $P$ of degree $\leq n$ such that $P + K$ is also irreducible satisfies $\mathcal{N}(n,K) \leq c\frac{q^n}{n^2}$ ($c$ depending on $K$).

*Webb, William A.*, [**Sieve methods for polynomial rings over finite fields**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(83)90062-8), J. Number Theory 16, 343-355 (1983). [ZBL0517.10049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0517.10049).

As per convention, we set $\lvert F \rvert = q^{\deg(F)}$.
Define
$$\mathscr{P} = \{P \textrm{ monic irreducible} : \lvert P \rvert \leq N^{1/2}\}$$
and
$$\mathscr{D} = \{D \textrm{ squarefree} : \forall P \mid D, \ P \in \mathscr{P}\}.$$
In the proof (Theorem 4 in the paper), it is claimed that $$\sum_{\substack{D \in \mathscr{D} \\ \lvert D \rvert \leq N^{1/4} \\ (D,K) = 1}} \frac{2^{\omega(D)}}{\lvert D \rvert} \geq c_1 \sum_{\substack{P \in \mathscr{P} \\ \lvert P \rvert \leq N^{1/4} \\ P \nmid K}} \left(1 - \frac{2}{\lvert P \rvert}\right)^{-1} \geq c_2 \log^2(N).$$
I suspect that the middle term in the previous inequality was supposed to be a product. Otherwise each term of the sum is $\geq 1$, and the sum should be $\gg \frac{N^{1/4}}{\log(N)}$ by counting irreducibles. So assuming a typo, I am trying to see why
$$\sum_{\substack{D \in \mathscr{D} \\ \lvert D \rvert \leq N^{1/4} \\ (D,K) = 1}} \frac{2^{\omega(D)}}{\lvert D \rvert} \geq c_1 \prod_{\substack{P \in \mathscr{P} \\ \lvert P \rvert \leq N^{1/4} \\ P \nmid K}} \left(1 - \frac{2}{\lvert P \rvert}\right)^{-1}.$$
Ignoring the coprimality condition with $K$ for the moment, I can see that
$$\prod_{\substack{P \in \mathscr{P} \\ \lvert P \rvert \leq N^{1/4}}} \left(1 - \frac{2}{\lvert P \rvert}\right)^{-1} \asymp \prod_{\substack{P \in \mathscr{P} \\ \lvert P \rvert \leq N^{1/4}}} \left(1 + \frac{2}{\lvert P \rvert}\right) \leq \prod_{\substack{P \in \mathscr{P} \\ \lvert P \rvert \leq N^{1/2}}} \left(1 + \frac{2}{\lvert P \rvert}\right) = \sum_{D \in \mathscr{D}} \frac{2^{\omega(D)}}{\lvert D \rvert},$$
but it seems that the terms in the right-most sum with $\lvert D \rvert \leq N^{1/4}$ would need to dominate the sum, which I have not been able to prove. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried applying Rankin's trick? When you only care for an upper or lower bound, then it can be very helpful for getting rid of unruly conditions restricting the size of a parameter, especially in sums over multiplicative functions like this one.

Comment: @AnuragSahay I was not familiar with Rankin's trick, so thank you for the suggestion! However, the examples I have seen are used to get lower bounds for finite sums, while I need an upper bound. I attempted replacing $\lvert D \rvert$ by $\lvert D \rvert^{1 + 1/\log(N)}$ and then bounding the tail of the sum over $\frac{2^\omega(D)}{\lvert D \rvert^{1 + 1/\log(N)}}$, but the issue is that the $D$ are sparse and the upper limit for $\lvert D \rvert$ is enormous (something like $N^{N^{1/4}/4\log(N)}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what Webb had in mind, but here is my answer. There is no real difference between the Selberg sieve in integers and in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$. So you can consult the book "Multiplicative Number Theory I" by Montgomery and Vaughan where the same upper bound is established in integers, and adapt their argument to $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$. Specifically see page 94, where a sum analogous to the one you ask about is estimated.

In more detail, the required estimate is
$$\sum_{\substack{D \in \mathscr{D} \\ \lvert D \rvert \leq N^{1/4} \\ (D,K) = 1}} \frac{2^{\omega(D)}}{\lvert D \rvert} \geq c \log^2(N).$$
For given $d\ge 0$ with $q^d \le N^{1/4}$, I claim that
$$(\star)\quad\sum_{\substack{D \in \mathscr{D} \\ \deg(D)=d \\ (D,K) = 1}} \frac{2^{\omega(D)}}{\lvert D \rvert} =q^{-d}\sum_{\substack{\deg(D)=d \\(D,K)=1}} 2^{\omega(D)} \mu^2(D) \ge c' d$$
if $d$ is sufficiently large (in terms of $K$). The constant $c'$ depends on $K$. Summing this over $d$ gives the needed bound.

To establish $(\star)$  write the arithmetic function $f(D)=2^{\omega(D)}\mu^2(D)\mathbf{1}_{(D,K)=1}$ as a convolution of the divisor function $\tau(D)$ with a simple multiplicative $g$. Since $\sum_{\deg(D)=d} \tau(D) = q^ d (d+1)$, the problem reduces to showing $\sum_{D}g(D)/\lvert D \rvert$ converges to a positive constant and $\sum_{D} g(D) \deg(D)/\lvert D \rvert$ converges absolutely. This is easily verified by considering the Dirichlet series of $g$ (as in page 94 of the aforementioned book).